# Is there an insert method on a Rust Vec, which fills missing indexes with the default value?

Tags: vector, rust

I want a method which works like this:

```
let mut vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
vec.<some_method>(3 /*index*/, 12 /*value*/);
// the indexes get filled with the default value for the type (i32)
// if the vec isn't long enough
assert_eq!(vec[..], [0, 0, 0, 12]);
```

Comment: There is no such method in the standard library, but you can build your own by calling `vec.resize_with(index + 1, Default::default)` first when required. It's not quite clear what your desired semantics are in case the index points to inside the vector, though – do you want to _insert_ the new value, shifting existing value to the right, or replace the existing value at the index?

Comment: As a side note, you may want to use a `HashMap` instead – it allows inserting new values at arbitrary keys.